# Problema al querer comparar dos contraseñas encriptadas SHA1 PHP

Tags: php, mysql

El problema que tengo es que no logro comparar las contraseñas para realizar el login de forma correcta en mi aplicación.
Con las pruebas que hice ya, pinté las dos contraseñas a comparar y si que son iguales, lo que no entiendo es porque no realiza el login.

```html
<?php
include "./database/database.php";
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['btnSubmit'])){
    $codigo = $_POST["codigo"];
    $password = sha1($_POST["password"]);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM profesores WHERE codigo ='$codigo'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    //posicion del campo password en la base de datos
    $pass = $row['2'];

    if($pass == $password){
        $_SESSION['codigo'] = $codigo;
        header("Location: ./index.php");
    }else{
        echo "<script>alert('Código o contraseña incorrectos');</script>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: ¿Dices que has pintado `$pass` y `$password` justo antes de la comparación, que sí que son iguales, y que no entra en el `if`? Eso es imposible, revísalo bien, algo se te está escapando.

Comment: Se recomienda el uso de [password_verify()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.password-verify.php) y de [password_hash()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.password-hash.php)